# Selecting from tables where same column equals two different things?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has 16 tables, but only four are relevant to this.  The database tracks different servers, the servers information (CPU, RAM, IP Address, etc) and the software it is running.  The software and machines are related through a join table.

```
CREATE TABLE machsoftjt (
     mid int(4) NOT NULL,
     sid int(4) NOT NULL,
     slid int(4) NOT NULL,
     notes varchar(255) default NULL,
     UNIQUE KEY mid (mid,slid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

mid is the machine's id from the machines table, sid is the software's id from the software table which contains the software's name and software's version, slid is the softwarelist id from the softlist table(a table with just lists the software being run and is used for unique constraint so that when software upgrades are performed I don't have an entry for one machine running two different versions of the same software).  So if I have machine1 (with a mid of 1) running Microsoft Word 2010 (with a sid of 1 and a slid of 1) and Adobe Photoshop 5 (with a sid of 2 and a slid of 2), the table would have

```
mid  sid   slid
1    1     1
1    2     2
```

I want to select from this table all machines that is running both Microsoft Word and Adobe Photoshop.

```
SELECT machines.machinename FROM (machines INNER JOIN machsoftjt ON 
  machines.mid=machsoftjt.mid) INNER JOIN software ON machsoftjt.sid=software.sid
  WHERE machsoftjt.slid='1' AND machsoftjt.slid='2'
```

When I run this query, I do not get anything backWhen I run this query, I do not get anything back.  And I am now stumped and can't come up with anything else.  All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide table layouts for machines and software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This calls for a self-join.  Roughly:

```
SELECT machines.machinename 
FROM machines 
INNER JOIN machsoftjt AS m1 ON machines.mid=m1.mid 
INNER JOIN machsoftjt AS m2 ON machines.mid=m2.mid 
WHERE m1.slid='1' AND m2.slid='2'
```

To get software names, roughly:

```
SELECT machines.machinename, s1.*, s2.*
FROM machines 
INNER JOIN machsoftjt AS m1 ON machines.mid=m1.mid 
INNER JOIN machsoftjt AS m2 ON machines.mid=m2.mid 
INNER JOIN software s1 ON m1.sid=s1.sid
INNER JOIN software s2 ON m2.sid=s2.sid
WHERE m1.slid='1' AND m2.slid='2'
```

You'll probably have to alias the relevant columns from s1 and s2

Comment: Thank you this works great!  What about if I wanted to also return back both (or however many I select - right now up to 6) software names and versions?

Comment: @ubuntu72 -- see my new edit.  Should give you the basic idea.

Comment: THANK YOU!! Works exactly like I want.  And when I want more than two I just do the same stuff just as s3 and so on?

Answer (score 2):

It's failing because of this line:

WHERE machsoftjt.slid='1' AND machsoftjt.slid='2'

machsoftjt can't be equal to both 1 and 2; so you're getting no results.

You'll have to query for each package separately.

I think that something like this should do it:

```
SELECT machines.machinename 
FROM machines 
WHERE mid IN (SELECT mid FROM machsoftht WHERE sid=1) AND 
 mid IN (SELECT mid FROM machsoftht WHERE sid=2)
```

Comment: Thank you this works great as well!  What about if I wanted to also return back both (or however many I select - right now up to 6) software names and versions?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for self-joins or subqueries:

Just join `machsoftjt` once, then to get machines satisfying **all** conditions, you can use a `HAVING` clause in conjunction with a `GROUP BY` to only retrieve machines in which *two rows joined* where software was *either Photoshop or Word*:

```
SELECT
    a.machinename
FROM
    machines a
INNER JOIN
    machsoftjt b ON a.mid = b.mid
    AND b.slid IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
    a.mid
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

Also, since `slid` is of type `INT`, you do not need quotation marks around `1` and `2`.

This approach is also flexible in that it's easy to add/remove conditions. If you wanted machines which had all `slid`s of (1,2,4,8), just adjust the `IN` clause and up the `COUNT(*)` in the `HAVING` clause to `4` (because there are 4 values in the list that the machine must satisfy).

Comment: Thank you this works great as well!  What about if I wanted to also return back both (or however many I select - right now up to 6) software names and versions?